# Are there any stunt jumps? Or are jumps just to break police pursuit?

Tags: sleeping-dogs

So I know there are a few special jumps in the game as when you go over them the screen turns grey. I got a tip about using them to break pursuit.

Do they have any other function? Is there a stunt jumps award or similar for completing these?

Comment: I've since noticed that once you jump them that they are marked on the mini-map as little grey arrows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They can be called stunt jumps, but there is nothing for jumping over them. You do not get anything by doing them. They can also be used to break police pursuits.